# Mocking an anonymous module call in Jasmine using requireJs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, requirejs, jasmine, chutzpah

Current unit testing setup:

- Jasmine 2.1
- RequireJs 2.1.15
- Chutzpah 3.2.6

In our code base we have a number of modules which are loaded in through requireJs to abstract out functionality. For example communications which abstracts away calls to the server. However these modules return an anonymous function:

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {

    return function (method, link, payload) {
        // code removed as not required for question
        return $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: link,
            data: payload
        });
    };
})
```

This is then imported through requireJs/AMD loading by other modules and used in the following way:

```
var promise = communicator("GET", "/url/to/my/webapi", {});
```

I currently have a mock module which gets imported for the unit tests bypassing the $.ajax call and returns a promise however I really want to test in my unit tests that it has been called or not and the correct values have been passed in etc. I have tried looking at spies however as it doesn't expose a named function on the module I am unable to use this method as far as I can tell.

How can I go about setting up expectations/mocking an anonymous AMD returned function?

**EDIT**

Example of usage to aid with clarity:

```
define(['communicator'], function (communicator) {

        var vm = function (id) {
            var self = this;

            self.Id = id

            self.submitForm = function () {
                var data = { };

                var promise = communicator("PUT", "/url/to/web/api", data);

                promise.done(function (message) {
                });

                promise.fail(function (error) {
                });
            };
        };

        return {
            initialise: function (params) {
                var viewModel = new vm(params.Id);
                return viewModel;
            }
        };
    });
```

I want to be able to test the submitForm function (simplified for question purposes) and want to mock the communicator dependency without defining a stubbed additional module in the testing project require.js setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you need to test, but you could spyOn `$.ajax` and create your own promise...

```
window.spyOn($, "ajax").and.callFake(function() {
  var d = $.Deferred();
  d.resolve(true);
  return d.promise();
});

expect($.ajax).toHaveBeenCalled();
// other expects...
```

Comment: I've used this technique to test the communicator module itself but don't want to mock the underlying dependencies of the communicator module when testing the "top level" module which depends on communicator.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went with changing the module to have specific methods on which could then be spied on. I have other modules which are of the same pattern though so will continue on my quest.